# Three.js stop render process

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, render

I have to load a big obj file, with computers that do not support WebGL load becomes too slow, so I have to upload a light object before and after the complete object. 
To do this I need to stop the rendering process when I rotate the view while it is still processing the complete object. Is there any function that solve that problem?Thanks!

my code:

```
    var renderWire = function () {
        renderer.render(wireScene, camera);
        render();
    };
    var render = function () {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).keypress(function(event) {
            switch(event.keyCode) {
                case 100: //destra
                    //rotation
                    break;
                case 97: //sinistra
                    //rotation
                    break;
                default:
                    //not set
                    break
            }

            //here i have to stop render if running and start a new render

            renderWire();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Actually loading a file has nothing to do with WebGL.

Answer (score 0):

I would attempt to load one object at time. This way you can control the flow of the loading process. It sounds like you need to load 3 objects

```
var firstTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/firstTexture.png", undefined, firstObject );
function firstObject ( texture ) {
            var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: texture } );
            firstObject = new THREE.Sprite( material );
            scene.add( firstObject );
            var secoundTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/secoundTexture.png", undefined, secoundObject );
        };

        function secoundObject ( texture ) {
            var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: texture } );
            secoundObject = new THREE.Sprite( material );
            scene.add( secoundObject );
            var thirdTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "images/thirdTexture.png", undefined, thirdObject );
        };

        function thirdObject ( texture ) {
            var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: texture } );
            thirdObject = new THREE.Sprite( material );
            scene.add( thirdObject );
            codeAfterloading();
        };

        function codeAfterloading () {

        };
```

I hope this helps you out.